# How to relate these two formulas of angular velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differentiation, geometry, angular-velocity

Consider the following picture:

[image]

with $\vec{v}(t)$ the velocity of a particle at time t, $\vec{a}(t)$ its acceleration at time t and $\vec{a_n}(t)$ its normal acceleration at time t.

**I want to calculate the angular velocity $\omega(t)$ of the particle from the reference of the center of the circumference tangent to each point of the trajectory.**

I can think of two ways to calculate it:

1. $$\omega(t) = \frac{d\alpha(t)}{dt}$$
2. $$\omega(t) = \frac{a_n}{v} = \frac{a \sin(\theta)}{v} = \frac{a}{v} \sqrt{1 - \left( \frac{\vec{v}  \cdot \vec{a}}{v \ a} \right)^2}$$

   where in the last step I have used:
   $$\sin \theta = \sqrt{ 1 - \cos^2 \theta }$$
   $$\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{v}  \cdot \vec{a}}{v \ a}$$

**Question:** *How can I show that both formulas 1. and 2. are equivalent?*

---

I thought of starting with 1. using:
$$ \cos( d\alpha(t) ) =  \frac{\vec{v}(t)  \cdot \vec{v}(t+dt)}{v(t) \ v(t+dt)}$$
and expanding $\vec{v}(t+dt)$ in terms of $dt$. But I get lost with the differentials and I haven't succeed in expressing it like 2.

Comment: which program you used for drawing?

Comment: I use Inkscape with the extension [TexText](https://inkscape.org/~jcwinkler/%E2%98%85textext) to write in Latex.

Comment: Why would you assume that ω = $a_n$/v?  Also, if 'ω' is constant, then' $a_n$' is the only component of acceleration.

Comment: @R.W.Bird I understand $\omega$ is not necessarily constant and the acceleration is not necessarily normal (otherwise the trajectory would be a circumference right?). I believe the normal acceleration can be expressed as $a_n = v^2 / r$ for $r$ the radius of the tangential circumference. Then, in that circumference you can express the instantaneous velocity $v = \omega \ r$. Combining both expressions, $\omega = a_n / v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with 2.:
$$\omega = \frac{a_n}{v}$$

considering $a_n = \omega^2 R$ and solving for $\omega$:

$$\omega = \frac{v}{R} = v \frac{d \alpha}{ds} = v \frac{d \alpha}{ds} \frac{dt}{dt} = v\frac{dt}{ds}  \frac{d \alpha}{dt}  =  \frac{d \alpha}{dt}, $$

where in the second step we used $ds = R d\alpha$ and in the last step $v= \frac{ds}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to relate the a and v to the angle $\alpha$.
You have $a=\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ and from the triangle with sides equal to v, v and $\Delta v $ you have $\Delta v = 2 v \sin(\frac{\Delta \alpha}{2})$ and $$ a= \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}= \frac{2 v}{\Delta t} \sin(\frac{\Delta \alpha}{2})$$
The angle $\theta$ is related to $\Delta \alpha $ by $\sin(\theta)=\cos(\frac{\Delta \alpha}{2})$ so when you put the parts together you have
$$\frac{a}{v} \sin(\theta)  =\frac{\sin(\Delta \alpha)}{\Delta t}$$ which for small angles tends to $\frac{\Delta \alpha}{\Delta t}$which in the limit  $\Delta t -> 0$ gives you the derivative in your first form.

Edit
Figure added for clarity.
[image]

Comment: Ah thank you, I understood everything except why $\sin(\theta)=\cos(\frac{\Delta \alpha}{2})$. Could you elaborate it a bit more or maybe show a picture?

Comment: From the triangle (assumed isosceles) you have $\theta = 90^o - \Delta \alpha/2$.

Comment: One of the two angles at the base is $(180 - \Delta \alpha)/2 $ and $\theta$ is the supplement of it.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see a triangle with both $\Delta \alpha$ and $\theta$. As far as I see, $\theta$ does not have any restriction, it only depends on the direction of the acceleration $\vec{a}$, which is arbitrary right?

Comment: I added a drawing to the answer. $\theta$ is not arbitrary. The acceleartion is along the direction of the vector $\Delta \vec{v} $ so the angle theta is between the vectors $\vec{v}$  and $\Delta \vec{v}$